# error: Packge R does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this message on Android Studio - error: Package R does not exist.

I have done the following:

1. tried to clean project/rebuild,
2. invalidate cache/restart.

Nothing seems to be working. Please assist.
But none seem to work.

Comment: What is package R? Where is it? Please explain a little more.

Comment: you need to elaborate, and show some code or more detail as to what you have so far...

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the android studio, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the package name.R and it worked
i.e. import com.projectname.R.

Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

you need to import package like 
import your package name.R;
if you don't know your package name and how to exactly write it , please check other activity in your project that doesn't have this problem.